# Random Array Sort Method Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, random, methods

Currently I'm building a quiz app, which displays a verb with a right and 3 wrong answers in a random order.
The class is:

```
class IrregularVerb {
    constructor(verb, right, wrongFirst, wrongSecond, wrongThird) {
        this._verb = verb;
        this._right = right;
        this._wrong = [wrongFirst, wrongSecond, wrongThird];
    }

    randomOrder() {
        return this._wrong.sort(0.5 - Math.random());
    }
}

const irregularVerbList = [
    new IrregularVerb("read", "read", "rode", "ride", "ridden"),
    new IrregularVerb("go", "went", "gone", "got", "god")
]


const randomWrongAnswer = irregularVerbList[randomNumber].randomOrder;
```

randomWrongAnswer should return an Array with the last 3 object parameters in a random order, but it displays "function randomOrder()". Is the method declaration or its call wrong?

Comment: You must *call* the method. Parentheses are missing. You just assigned the function object instead of the function call's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 3 things to fix

```js
class IrregularVerb {
  constructor(verb, right, wrongFirst, wrongSecond, wrongThird) {
    this._verb = verb;
    this._right = right;
    this._wrong = [wrongFirst, wrongSecond, wrongThird];
  }

  randomOrder() {
    return this._wrong.sort(()=>0.5 - Math.random());
    //                      ^^^^  Need these parentheses and fat arrow
    //                            to make it a function
  }
}

const irregularVerbList = [
  new IrregularVerb("read", "read", "rode", "ride", "ridden"),
  new IrregularVerb("go", "went", "gone", "got", "god")
]


const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
// Need this so that randomNumber is not undefined

const randomWrongAnswer = irregularVerbList[randomNumber].randomOrder();
//                           Need this to actually call the function ^^
console.log(randomWrongAnswer)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the syntax is pretty new to me. Wish you a wonderful day!